# VueJS - reusing prop (field name) at definition of other bindigns

Tags: vue.js

I don't know how to exactly name this, I have some sort of forms in Vue which consist of different input types or more complex wrapped elements or even custom components. They all have one thing in common though - their fieldName which is used for checking various stuff such as validation, class binding etc.

Example:

```
 <div class="field">
     <div class="label">Product name</div>
     <input :value="productName" @input="valueChanged" :class="{ changed: isChanged('productName') }" data-field="productName">
</div>
```

As you can see, `productName` is repeated 3 times in just a single line. I use it in dataset so `valueChanged` method (a global mixin) knows that field name has changed, then in the class binding to check if value has changed to style it properly, and next for the value binding itself.

It grows bigger and bigger as I want to add for example another class binding like `error: hasErrors('productName')`

Is there any way to define the field name once and re-use it in other bindings? It would still require some repetition, but at least changing the field name in the future would be just one change instead of 4-5. Something like this:

```
<input :fName="productName" :value="fName" @input="valueChanged" :class="{changed: isChanged(fName), error: hasErrors(fName)" :data-field="fName">
```

I know that wrapping it in some custom component would probably be one way, but that would require a lot of different conditions to render things correctly as I'm using various field types with different structures. And I would need to re-write half of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two potential solutions:

1. Use `v-bind` and generate an object with all of the attributes you need

```
<input v-bind="getAttrs('productName')" @input="valueChanged" />

...

methods: {
  getAttrs(fieldName) {
    return {
      value: this[fieldName],
      class: {
        changed: this.isChanged(fieldName),
        error: this.hasErrors(fieldName)
      },
      'data-field': fieldName
    }
  }
}
```

2. Store all the fields in a variable and loop through them:

```
<div
  v-for="field in fields"
  class="field"
>
  <div class="label">
    Product name
    // Or e.g. {{ field.label }} if you have an array of field objects
  </div>
  <input
    :value="getValue(field)"
    :class="{ changed: isChanged(field), error: hasErrors(field) }"
    // Still need to use v-bind to generate the data attribute on the fly
    v-bind="getDataAttr(field)"
    @input="valueChanged"
  />
</div>

...

data() {
  return {
    fields: [
      'fieldName1',
      'fieldName2',
      'fieldName3'
    ],
  }
},
methods: {
  getValue(fieldName) {
    return this[fieldName];
  },
  getDataAttr(fieldName) {
    return {
      'data-field': fieldName
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that having custom component handling input fields is the smartest way. I don't think, there would be that much conditions and even if there is some workaround, you will still need to rewrite half of your app. You may use input `type` as prop, so you can use component for different field types and if there are much different structures, you can use `slots`, to add some custom structure.